# Listagem de array com inicio e fim

Tags: php, array

Exemplo..

```
$inicio = '11:00';
$fim = '13:00';
$array = ['10:00', '10:30', '11:00', '11:30', '12:00', '12:30', '13:00', '13:30'];
```

preciso listar o array.. mas usando o valor inicio e o valor final.. excluindo oque estiver antes do `$inicio`.. e oque estiver depois do `$final`.

ficando então só.

```
$array = ['11:00', '11:30', '12:00', '12:30', '13:00'];
```

Comment: todos os elementos do array vão ser horas?

Comment: sim mano.. exatamente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faça um validação dos 2 valores e popule um array.

```
$inicio = '12:00';
$fim = '13:00';
$array = ['10:00', '10:30', '11:00', '11:30', '12:00', '12:30', '13:00', '13:30'];
$times = [];
foreach($array as $time){
    if( ($time >= $inicio && $time <=$fim ) ){
        array_push($times, $time);
    }
}
var_dump($times);
```

Comment: Seria legal usar `$times[]  = $time` ao invés de `array_push`, pois isso torna o código mais performático.

Comment: vlw @WallaceMaxters, vou usar sim.

Comment: Mano @LuizPillon.. perfeito.. porém precisou ser $times = array();

Comment: mas provavelmente porque to usando Laravel.. só não usei array_push.. setei diretamente.. como o WallaceMaxters citou!. enfim vlw mano obrigado.. to fazendo tanta coisa que nem sei porque não consegui pensar nisso kkk.

Comment: maravilha! provavelmente voce está rodando o php < 5.4

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php) para fazer o cálculo. Em PHP, mesmo se tratando de `string` é possível fazer as comparações:

```
$horas = array_filter($array, function ($hora) use ($inicio, $fim) {
    return $hora >= $inicio && $hora <= $fim;
});
```

Essa função criará um novo `array` baseando-se no resultado da expressão booleana retornada pela função. Se for verdadeira, o item é mantido no `array`. Se for falsa, é ignorada.

É importante ressaltar que as chaves são mantidas quando você usa `array_filter`. Caso necessite reordenar o `array`, você pode chamar `array_values` para resolver o problema:

```
$horas = array_filter($array, function ($hora) use ($inicio, $fim) {
    return $hora >= $inicio && $hora <= $fim;
});

$horas = array_values($horas);
```

Comment: É importante salientar que as chaves são mantidas e, portanto, deve-se tomar muito cuidado ao acessar os valores. No exemplo dado na pergunta, os índices seriam de 2 a 6, gerando erro ao tentar acessar `$horas[0]`, por exemplo.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss prontinho :p

Comment: Cara muito top sua dica mano.. obrigado mano

Answer (score 1):

Apenas para conhecimento. Caso esteja trabalhando com a data completa e apenas as horas são importante. Você pode resolver o problema facilmente utilizando o [DateTime](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.datetime.php).

```
$inicio = new DateTime('2017-08-07 11:00:00');
$fim = new DateTime('2017-08-07 13:00:00');

$array = [
    '2017-08-07 10:00:00',
    '2017-08-07 10:30:00',
    '2017-08-07 11:00:00',
    '2017-08-07 11:30:00',
    '2017-08-07 12:00:00',
    '2017-08-07 12:30:00',
    '2017-08-07 13:00:00',
    '2017-08-07 13:30:00'
];


$horas = [];
foreach($array as $hora) {
    $hora = new DateTime($hora);
    if ($hora >= $inicio && $hora <= $fim) {
       array_push($horas, $hora->format('H:i'));
    }
}

var_dump($horas);

//Saída
//array(5) {
//    [0]=>
//  string(5) "11:00"
//    [1]=>
//  string(5) "11:30"
//    [2]=>
//  string(5) "12:00"
//    [3]=>
//  string(5) "12:30"
//    [4]=>
//  string(5) "13:00"
//}
```

Comment: vlw mano pela atenção.. não tava usando não.. é só a data mesmo.. mas vlw pela dica.. quem sabe outro dia eu precise.. haha! vlw irmão obrigado!